# Service discovery on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kube-dns

I have kubeDNS set up on a bare metal kubernetes cluster.  I thought that would allow me to access services as described [here](https://fabric8.io/guide/services.html#service-discovery-via-dns) (http:// for those who don't want to follow the link), but when I run

```
curl https://monitoring-influxdb:8083
```

I get the error

> curl: (6) Could not resolve host: monitoring-influxdb

This is true when I run curl on a service name in any namespace.  Is this an error with my kubDNS setup or are there different steps I need to take in order to achieve this?  I get the expected output when I run the test at the end of [this article](http://jamiehannaford.com/setting-up-dns-discovery-in-kubernetes/).

For reference:

[kubeDNS controller yaml files](https://pastebin.com/GJrpvSZw)

[kubeDNS service yaml file](https://pastebin.com/YXHsaZW9)

[kubelet flags](https://pastebin.com/vYmMgVF7)

[output of kubectl get svc in default and kube-system namespaces](https://pastebin.com/acrFcq4i)

Comment: From where do you run the `curl` command? From within the cluster?

Comment: Yes, from the master node

Comment: The article is showing you getting service discovery from one Pod to another, so to match it you should run your curl command from an interactive session within a Pod/container. You might also double check that it matches the service discovery pattern - i.e. <servicename>.<namespace> or <servicename>.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local per the docs at https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/

Comment: @Ryan this needs to be run from within Kubernetes. Create a pod in the namespace `kube-system` and try it from within the pod.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Michael Hausenblas pointed out in the comments, `curl http://monitoring-influxdb:8086` needs to be run from within a pod.  Doing that provided the expected results

Answer (score 6):

The service discovery that you're trying to is documented at https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-serv‌​ice, and is for communications *within* one pod talking to an existing service, not from nodes (or the master) to speak to Kubernetes services.

You will want to leverage the DNS for the service in form of `<servicename>.<namespace>` or `<servicename>.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local`. To see this in operation, kick up an interactive pod with busybox (or use an existing pod of your own) with something like:

- `kubectl run -i --tty alpine-interactive --image=alpine --restart=Never`

and within that shell that is provided there, make an nslookup command. From your example, I'm guessing you're trying to access influxDB from https://github.com/kubernetes/heapster/tree/master/deploy/kube-config/influxdb, then it will be installed into the `kube-system` namespace, and the service name you'd use from another Pod internally to the cluster would be:

- `monitoring-influxdb.kube-system.svc.cluster.local`

For example:

```
kubectl run -i --tty alpine --image=alpine --restart=Never
If you don't see a command prompt, try pressing enter.
/ # nslookup monitoring-influxdb.kube-system.svc.cluster.local
Server:    10.96.0.10
Address 1: 10.96.0.10 kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local

Name:      monitoring-influxdb.kube-system.svc.cluster.local
Address 1: 10.102.27.233 monitoring-influxdb.kube-system.svc.cluster.local
```